# JS script fails parsing. Is it expression which is too long or something else?

Tags: javascript

I have errors in my js code below :
"Missing semicolon.
Expected an identifier and instead saw '=='.
Expected an operator and instead saw 'typeof'.
Unnecessary directive 'undefined'.
Do not use String as a constructor.
Assignment in conditional expression 'a' is already defined.
Missing '()' invoking a constructor.
eval can be harmful."

Thanks to syntax coloring, I noticed that my code is properly parsed until one point.   & I can't figure out why.  May be one of you can unstuck me ?

```
jaxon.tools._getFormValues=function(e,a,t,n){
  for(var r=a.length,o=0;r>o;++o){
    var s=a[o];
    "undefined"!=typeof s.childNodes&&"select-one"!=s.type&&"select-multiple"!=s.type&&jaxon.**tools**._getFormValues(e,s.childNodes,t,n),jaxon.tools._getFormValue(e,s,t,n)
  }
},
jaxon.tools._getFormValue=function(e,a,t,n){
  if(a.name&&"PARAM"!=a.tagName&&!(a.disabled&&1==a.disabled&&0==t||n!=a.name.substring(0,n.length)...))
  {...}
}
```

The syntax coloration disappears from where you see the double stars ** onward till end of line : jaxon.**tools**._getFormValues(e,s.childNodes,t,n)

Either there is something I dont see ?
Or may be expression is just too long (I copy pasted sample from a longer expression) ?

Thanks for your help

```
Best regards

KNE
```

Comment: the only issue with your code is the `...` at `a.name.substring(0,n.length)...` and `{...}`

Comment: read the error - it has nothing to do with where you marked your code

Comment: Hi @JaromandaX
The 3 dots are to be read as a placeholder.
I also believe that the errors displayed do not point the issue but are displayed as a consequence of the issue
Still searching

Comment: sure, I realise ... I'm saying there's no error in the *code you posted*

Comment: oh, wait ... I think some linters don't like that style of statement ... `a && b && c && fn()` - you may just need to write it like `if (a && b && c) { fn() }`

Answer (score 0):

No particular error in this case rather warnings
Syntax color was lost at some point because source file is huge and was written without spaces, nor carriage return, nor indentation.
(sorry)
Thank you @Jaromanda X
Cheers !